# Convert NSUrl to NSData or NSStream for opening

Tags: ios, nsurl, appdelegate

Suppose my app gets a call to:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app 
        openURL:(NSURL *)url 
        options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options;
```

But what I am really interested in is not the URL, it's the data that the URL will lead me to. Is there a unified way to get the data out of the URL? (say an `NSData` or `NSStream` object). Or do I have to go parsing the URL to see what kind of URL it is (file, etc.), then use an appropriate method to get the data?

Comment: You are the creator of the app — so it should be you knowing what your app is intended to do when it receives an url.

Answer (score 0):

You can always load the data from the URL and then do something with it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // do something with the data
        NSLog(@"data: %@", data);
    }];

    [task resume];

    return YES;
}
```